# Create time intervals using a column in R

Tags: r, time, dataframe, intervals, element

I have a column of a data frame that consists of dates, let's say in this form

```
    d$x<-c("2014-05-01 11:36:12", "2014-05-01 11:36:14", "2014-05-01 11:36:15",
           "2014-05-01 11:36:16", "2014-05-01 11:36:16", "2014-05-01 11:36:17")
```

and want to build intervals with

- min: element - 60 seconds and
- max: element + 60 seconds

for each row.
Then I have to find whether another column's elements, suppose it is

```
    d$y<-c("2014-05-01 11:38:21", "2014-05-01 11:42:26", "2014-05-01 11:47:37",
           "2014-05-01 11:53:44" ,"2014-05-01 11:59:23", "2014-05-01 12:04:39")
```

belongs in any of these intervals or not.

I used the `for` loop and `if`, but my data are very long so this does not seem like a good option to me. `length(d$x)` is around 36000  and `length(d$y) = 100`. Here's my current code:

```
$k<-rep(0,length(d$x))
for (i in 1:(length(d$y))) {
  for (j in 1:(d$x)) {
    if ((d$y[i] <= d$x[j]+60) & (d$y[i] >=d$x[j]-60))
      k[i]=i
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sqldf` package:

```
#data
datx <- data.frame(x=as.POSIXct(c("2014-05-01 11:36:12",
                                  "2014-05-01 11:36:14",
                                  "2014-05-01 11:36:15",
                                  "2014-05-01 11:36:16",
                                  "2014-05-01 11:36:16",
                                  "2014-05-01 11:36:17")))
daty <- data.frame(y=as.POSIXct(c("2014-05-01 11:38:21",
                                  "2014-05-01 11:42:26",
                                  "2014-05-01 11:38:33",
                                  "2014-05-01 11:53:44",
                                  "2014-05-01 11:59:23",
                                  "2014-05-01 12:04:39")))

myInterval <- 180 #3*60sec = 3 minutes

require(sqldf)
#get y within x +/-interval
res <-
  fn$sqldf("SELECT distinct(b.y)
         FROM datx a, daty b
         WHERE b.y BETWEEN a.x-$myInterval 
         AND a.x+$myInterval")
#output
res
#                   y
# 1 2014-05-01 11:38:21
# 2 2014-05-01 11:38:33
#get index
which(daty$y %in% res$y)
# [1] 1 3
```